# Trigger View action from ViewModel without data

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I am currently observing some data in my `ViewModel`. As soon as this data gets changed my `ViewModel` is informed and runs some computations. After that it shall trigger some action in my view. That is obviously not possible in a direct way due to loosley coupling. So I created some `LiveData` that emits a value after the computations which can be observed by the view to trigger the appopriate action (i.e. start a fragment). My problem here is that I hava to have some data to be emitted for the `LiveData`, but I don't need any data to trigger that action.

Example:

```
public class LandingViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "LandingViewModel";

    private final SessionKeyDao sessionKeyDao;
    private final CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private final MutableLiveData<Void> showGameFragment = new MutableLiveData<>();

    @Inject
    public LandingViewModel(final ProtocolMessageRepository protocolMessageRepository, final SessionKeyDao sessionKeyDao) {
        this.sessionKeyDao = sessionKeyDao;

        compositeDisposable.add(protocolMessageRepository.getStartGameReponse()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::OnStartGame, LandingViewModel::onError)
        );
    }

    private static void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
        Log.d(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        compositeDisposable.clear();
    }

    public LiveData<Void> getShowGameFragment() {
        return showGameFragment;
    }

    private void OnStartGame(final StartGameResponse startGameResponse) {
        sessionKeyDao.save(new SessionKey(startGameResponse.getSessionId()));
        showGameFragment.postValue(null);
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to approch this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pending intent get pending intent to constructor of view model through factory then use pending intent with calling send of it

```
class LandingViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

  PendingIntent pi;

   public LandingViewModelFactory(PendingIntent pi){
     super();
     this.pi = pi;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
      return (T) new LandingViewModel(pi);;
   }
}

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, recCode, intent, flag);
// get pi to view model constructor through factory

viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new LandingViewModelFactory(pi)).get(LandingViewModel.class)   

//--------------------------------view model
public class LandingViewModel extends ViewModel {
    PendingIntent pi;

   public LandingViewModel(PendingIntent pi){
        this.pi = pi;
   }
   // then call send in view model when you need to start activity
   private void OnStartGame(final StartGameResponse startGameResponse) {
       sessionKeyDao.save(new SessionKey(startGameResponse.getSessionId()));
       pi.send();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this approch contradicts the MVVM paradigm. That way it's not loosley coupled anymore.

Comment: @Collo I do not think firing a pending intent violates MVVM because you do not modify pending intent inside ViewModel. you create pending intent inside View part and fire it WITHOUT KNOWING ANYTHING ABOUT IT inside ViewModel

Comment: If I do it that way my ViewModel knows something about my View. Maybe not in a direct way, but it's not loosley coupled anymore. So in that case you are approching I could rather use a callback method which I create in my View and pass it to the ViewModel.

Comment: @Collo `PendingIntent` is designed to be send between decoupled elements even it can be send between two processes.